# Display images with specific links

Tags: 7, views, media

I created a *Banner* content type, which has an image and a Link fields. I allowed the upload of multiple images and adding multiple links in this content type.

I am using the [Image Link Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_link_formatter) module, which adds a formatter to display an image with a link. This works fine when I add a Banner node and preview it. I want this banner to be displayed by the [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work in a view block. When I choose to display the content, it renders all the banner images in a single slide (as might be expected). When I select the banner image field only, and choose the Image Link formatter, it displays the banner images, but not the links.

I tried hiding the link field, but this has no effect.

As an alternative solution, I tried following [HOW TO INSTALL & SETUP VIEWS SLIDESHOW MODULE ON DRUPAL7?](http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-install-views-slideshow-module-on-drupal7) which suggests to use the *Output this field as a link* option for the image (which I did) and set it to the link field. This doesn't work as expected: The mapping multiplied the amount of banners, and output each banner once for eachlink.

How should I accomplish what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Instead of the Image Link Formatter, try outputting as a link via "Rewrite Results" - that's the way I always do it and I can't recall having a problem

Comment: That's not something I've tried; the idea of Views Slideshow is that it creates multiple slides, each slide represented by a single node. What you want to do makes sense conceptually, but it's not how the module was written to handle things

Comment: I believe this approach is not the best practice in Drupal -> one node, multiple links and images. One reason is exactly the problem you are facing! even though it seems tidy, it causes more headache later. Later you may decide to **reuse** your content and all of them aggregated in one node cause more trouble.

Comment: So I would put one link and one image in a node, follow Clive's approach, and if I needed to link multiple images and links together I'd create a second content type with a [entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by the comments posted under the question, the problem is that there are multiple images on a single node. To avoid problems like this, there should be one node per slide.